# How to iterate conclusion clauses in a judgement rule?

Tags: logic, branching-rules

Here is my case:

$$
\frac{\vdash f(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)}{\vdash t(a_1) \vdash t(a_2) \dots \vdash t(a_n)}
$$

I'm trying to make my conclusion part more compact. I'm thinking about something like this:

$$
\frac{\vdash f(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)}{\vdash_{i=1}^n t(a_i)}
$$

Is it the right way to do this?

Comment: See [Multiple-conclusion logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-conclusion_logic). Maybe it is enough to write the conclusion as $\vdash t(a_1), \ldots, t(a_n)$

Comment: [Hypersequents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersequent) may also be of interest.